# Калькулятор массива. Знак деления не правильно вычисляет данные из массива(поочередно)

Tags: javascript

```js
var arr = [];

while (true) {
  var value = prompt('Введите массив цифр через enter','Введите пустую строку,что бы остановить счисление');
  if (value === null || value === '') break;
  else if ( isNaN(value) ) continue;
  arr.push(value);
}

while (true) {
  var sign = prompt('Какой результат желаете? ','+ - * /');
  if (sign == '+')  {
    alert('+');

    var res = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      res += +arr[i];
    }
    alert(res);
  } else if (sign == '-') {
    alert('-')

    var res = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      res -= +arr[i];
    }
    alert(res);

  } else if (sign == '*') {
    alert('*')

    var res = 1;

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      res *= +arr[i];//res = res * arr[i];
    }
    alert(res);

  } else if (sign == '/') {
    alert('/')

    var res = 1;

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) { //изменить цикл,что бы числа делились один за другим в цикле. т.е i[1] =30 i[2]=5 res=6 ;
      //i[1] =30 i[2]=5 i[3]=3 res=2; arr.length-1 поскольу arr[i+1] при последнем i в цикле выдаст undefined,но это не точно.
      res += arr[i+1]/arr[i];
    }
    alert(res);

  } else if (sign == '') {
    break;
  } else  {
    alert('SyntaxError: expected expression '+sign);
  }
}
```

Comment: "Неправильно вычисляет" совершенно неинформативно и может привести к закрытию вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас и вычитание, кажется, неверно работает. При массиве `[3, 2]` получается `-5`, а должно, вроде бы, `1`, если не подразумевается условие, что первое число в ряду будет всегда `0`. То есть ваш способ со сложением не получается использовать в дальнейшем.

Попробуйте каждый раз присваивать начальной переменной первый элемент в массиве, а дальше начинать со второго и применять знак с присвоением. Что-то вроде этого:

```js
var res = +arr[0];

// дальше в зависимости от знака:

for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
  res += +arr[i];
}

for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
  res -= +arr[i];
}

for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
  res *= +arr[i];
}

for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
  res /= +arr[i];
}
```

Можно ещё использовать [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Comment: да я ломал голову над минусом,потому что выглядит глупо,что он просто складывает и возвращает знак на противоположный. Благодарю.